# Calculate a value between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I got this in a table:

```
id  dateFrom   hours
1  2013-02-01   6
2  2013-04-01   8
```

The `hours` represent the hours during a month, starting at that date, valid until next record.

I need to know how to sum the **hours for month** between two dates.

For example if range dates are ***2013-02-01*** to ***2013-06-01***:

```
6hs for february +
6hs for march +
8hs for april + 
8hs for may +
8hs for june
========
36 hs
```

Comment: According to example calculation and data provided seems that you have more hidden logic.

Comment: Indeed, this question is currently unclear. @user1750751, please elaborate.

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. Give us some test data, expected result and show what you tried

Comment: I've edited question to make it a bit easier to understand.

Comment: That's a good edit @NenadZivkovic, I think the question is very clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SET @startDate = '20130201'
SET @endDate   = '20130601'

;WITH CTE_Months AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate DT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MM,1,DT) FROM CTE_Months  
    WHERE DATEADD(MM,1,DT) <= @endDate
)
,CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DT ORDER BY dateFrom DESC) RN
    FROM CTE_Months m
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t ON m.DT >= t.dateFrom 
)
SELECT SUM(hours) 
FROM CTE_RN WHERE RN = 1
```

First recursive CTE is to find gaps between two dates, second CTE using `ROW_NUMBER` and `JOIN` on actual table to find hours for each month. At the end, just sum `WHERE RN=1`

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6e2b/2)**

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is actually two fold here. First we need to normalise it so we get actual month,hourPermonth tuples. We need to create month increments between row n and row n+1 and give them each the hours value of the original table.

I solved it by using an inline table-valued function that you can call or cross apply with parameters.

Complete solution to test here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7e58/1

Sample code for the function and how to call it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetSum(@startDate date,@endDate date)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
WITH cte as
(
SELECT @startDate as s
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(month,1,s)
FROM cte WHERE s<@endDate
)
SELECT
SUM(hours) as sumHours
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (SELECT top 1 h.hours FROM dbo.hourInterval as h WHERE h.startdate <= cte.s order by h.startdate desc) as t
)
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetSum('2013-02-01','2013-06-01')
```

Comment: No its wrong. I dont have records between february and april so, the result of that query is 14 hs.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, the original post didn't describe this very well. So you mean you first want to normalise it as month,hourForMonth and then sum it?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so good. I edit the post. Yes, I want to sum the hours by month between two dates. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer with what I think you actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I get it.  The `hours` represent the hours during a month, starting at that date.  You then want to add things up by month.

The following uses a recursive CTE to calculate one day in each month.  It then joins to your table, and chooses the most recent row before the current row.  Finally, it adds up the hours:

```
declare @fromdate date = '2013-02-01';
declare @todate date = '2013-06-01';

with months as (
      select @fromdate as thedate
      union all
      select DATEADD(month, 1, thedate)
      from months
      where DATEADD(month, 1, thedate) <= @todate
     ),
     t as (
      select 1 as id, CAST('2013-02-01' as DATE) as datefrom, 6 as hours union all
      select 2, '2013-04-01', 8
     )
select SUM(hours)
from (select t.*, m.thedate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by m.thedate order by t.datefrom desc) as seqnum
      from months m join
           t
           on m.thedate >= t.datefrom
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```